# iphone : install developer build into devices not added to provisioning

Tags: iphone, objective-c, provisioning

A have created a build. with a provisioning profile. Now there is a new device i have to install the build. but that is not in the provisioning.

Now i have to modify the provisioning. add device into it. download provisioning again and build again with new provisioning. now this new build will be installed into new provisioning.

this whole process is very hectic. is there any way through which i can add the devices into the provisioning after the build is created. and i dont have to create a new build each time a new device is added into the provisioning.

Please share ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to rebuild the app if you've simply added a device to the provisioning profile. Just install the updated profile on the device, then install the build.